# Trying to understand how to check subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm still trying to understand subspaces. Here is my problem.

> Given subspaces $H$ and $K$ of a vector space $V$, the sum of H and K, written $H + K$, is the set of all vectors in $V$ that can be written as the sum of two vectors, one in H and the other in $K$; that is H+K={w|w=u+v for some u in H and some v in K}.
>
> i.  Show that $H + K$ is a subspace of $V$.
>   
>   ii.  Show that $H$ is a subspace of $H + K$ and $K$ is a subspace of $H + K$.

For part (i) I did check $H+K$ using the zero vector. Here's my work.

> $H+K=0$
>   if $H+K=0$ then $0\in H$ and $0\in K$ which passes the zero vector property because $0+0=0 \in H+K$

Am I on the right track with this? Also, I want to show work for checking the other two checks in subspaces. I don't understand them enough to confidently say I can come up with something but if I had to guess, could I do the following.

> Check for closed under vector addition
>   Let use $H_1 + K_1$ and $H_2 + K_2$. 
>  
>   $H_1 + K_1$ = $H_2 + K_2$ 
>   $(H_1 + K_1) + (H_2 + K_2) = 0$ 
>   $H_1 + K_1 + H_2 + K_2 = 0$ 
>   $H_3 + K_3= 0$
>
> Check for closed under vector Multiplication
>   Let's use c as the scalar. 
>   $c * (H+K)$
>   $cH+cK$

Can someone explain the last two checks for me (whether I'm right or wrong) please? I don't understand them completely. In what scenario will they prove that a vector is not a subspace type? So far I always get problems where they are all subspaces.

For step (ii) i'm not sure what to do to show that $H$ and $K$ are subspaces of $H+K$

Comment: Do you know about the one-step test to check if a subset of a vector space is a subspace? Namely, if $U\subseteq V$, then $U$ is a subspace iff $\forall~u,v\in U$, we have $u+\lambda v\in U$ for all scalars $\lambda$

Comment: For problem (ii), you just need to show that $H,K\subseteq H+K$ (which is pretty obvious since $0\in H,K$) because you're already given that $H$ and $K$ are subspaces of $V$.

Comment: The notation $H+K = 0$ is misleading, because it looks like you're trying to prove that $H+K$ is the trivial ("zero") vector space containing only the zero vector. Rather, you should say that since both H and K are subspaces, then $ 0 \in H $ .... (and the rest of your that proof is okay).  
As for closure under vector addition and scalar multiplication, you again seem to be confusing _spaces_ with _vectors_. You should be trying to prove that if $u \in H+K$ and $v \in H+K$, then $u+v \in H+K$, and for scalar multiplication, if $u \in H+K$ and c is some scalar, then $cu \in H+K$